# t-test versus One-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test

I have a 50 question/Likert style survey that is broken into 7 subscores.  I am surveying two groups (teachers from four-day schools and five-day schools).

For each of the subscores, should I run a ttest or one-way ANOVA to determine if there is a significant difference?  It seems to me the tests tell me the same thing...so is there an advantage to using the ANOVA?

Thanks

Comment: what are your question items ? How do you assign scores to each category of your question item(s) ? what can I understand - "For each of the subscores " ?

Answer (score 1):

@Casey is correct that the Anova will provide identical results to the t-test in the case you have two categories. However, there are some other issues you might consider: First, you are will be doing 7 t-tests, so multiple comparisons are a concern. Adjusting for false discovery rate might be an option here. see, e.g. http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~genovese/talks/hannover1-04.pdf

Second, depending on the inter-relationships between the items and what your research question is, you might want to consider a more complex model which combines the sub scales. Something like CFA/SEM (implemented in the lavaan package) might be an option, and Manova might also be appropriate.

Comment: Please read my comment under the question cited above ?

Answer (score 0):

The tests practically give the same outcome. a T-Test provides the comparison of mean data between two groups, where as ANOVA is used for three or more groups. personally i would say use a T-Test.